# Need Help Replacing Number Divisible by 3 & 5 inside an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to print numbers 1-100 while replacing any number divisible by 3 inside my array to the string "Ping" and any number divisible by 5 to "Pong" and if there is a number that is divisible by both 3 & 5 to be replace by the word "PingPong". So instead of number 3 it should say Ping, and for 5 it should say Pong and so on.

Here is my code, I am failing to see where I went wrong:

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
  const numCount = document.querySelector('.count');
  const button = document.querySelector('.num-count');


  const numArr = []

  for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      if (numArr[i] % 3 == 0) {
          numArr[i] == "Ping"
      } else if (numArr[i] % 5 == 0) {
          numArr[i] == "Pong"
      } else if (numArr[i] % 3 == 0 && numArr[i] % 5 == 0) {
          numArr[i] == "PingPong"
      };
      numArr.push(i);

  };
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      numCount.textContent = numArr;
  });
```

```css
.count {
        font-size: 12px;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="num-count">Click Me!</button>
    <div class="count"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few issues, here we first initialize the array with the values from 1 to 100.

Then inside your loop first check if it is divisible by 3 and 5 because the other 2 conditions are included in this.

In your order it would never reach the *3 and 5* condition because it would be divisible by 3 or 5 before.

Also note *===* is for comparison and *=* is for assigning a value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    .count {
      font-size: 12px;
      padding-top: 30px;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="num-count">Click Me!</button>
  <div class="count"></div>

  <script>
    const numCount = document.querySelector('.count');
    const button = document.querySelector('.num-count');


    const numArr = []
    // first initialize the array with the values
    for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      numArr[i] = i;
    }

    for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      if (numArr[i] % 3 === 0 && numArr[i] % 5 === 0) {

        numArr[i] = "PingPong"
      } else if (numArr[i] % 5 === 0) {
        numArr[i] = "Pong"
      } else if (numArr[i] % 3 === 0) {
        numArr[i] = "Ping"
      };

    };
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      numCount.textContent = numArr;
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove else if  and just add if.
2. Use assignment operator for assigning not equality operator

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (numArr[i] % 3 == 0) {
        numArr[i] = "Ping"
    }
    if (numArr[i] % 5 == 0) {
        numArr[i] = "Pong"
    }
    if (numArr[i] % 3 == 0 && numArr[i] % 5 == 0) {
        numArr[i] = "PingPong"
    }
    else{
      numArr.push(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let numArr = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
        numArr.push("PingPong");
    } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
        numArr.push("Ping");
    } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
        numArr.push("Pong");
    }else{
        numArr.push(i);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

Firstly, assignment requires only one = sign, so you didn't change "i" correctly.

Secondly, you checked if the value of numArray at the index of i is divisible or not, and because you are dynamically adding values to the list it doesn't have numbers at those indexes.

Thirdly, changing the type of a variable mid-run is bad practice, I recommend introducing an output string, this also lets you cut the number of ifs, as I show below.

I modified the for loop to work:

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    let output = i.toString()
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
        output = "Ping"
    }
    if (i % 5 === 0) {
        output += "Pong"
    }
    numArr.push(output);

}
```